# MIPS Line by Line Read Error, occasionally double prints characters or adds extra newlines

Tags: assembly, mips

Using MIPS I am trying to read in a single line of a text file and then print it out to console. Specifically each line of the text file will contain 8 hexadecimal digits.

```
    .data
buffer:
    .space 1024


    .text

main:

    #open file
    li $v0, 13
    la $a0 filename
    li $a1, 0
    li $a2, 0
    syscall
    move $s0, $v0

    #read file
readline:
    li $v0, 14
    move $a0, $s0
    la $a1, buffer
    li $a2, 8
    syscall
    
    beq $v0, $zero, done_input

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, buffer
    syscall

    j readline

done_input:
    
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Here is my code, the problem I'm having is that the output from the console is not matching up with whats in the text file. It will randomly add extra a repeat of a number for some reason I do not understand or depending on the value in a2 when reading the line it will add a extra newline between outputs of lines.

sample.text contents:

```
12345678
23456789
34567890
```

Output with a2 set to 8

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the buffer contents after your 8-byte reads, using the debugger?  Your text file has newlines, but if those are DOS-style CR/LF line endings that carriage-return might come in the middle of some later read?  What MIPS simulator are you using (MARS or SPIM?), and on what OS, what are the `sample.txt` contents in binary?

Comment: Also, you have a label called `readline`, but it only reads a fixed 8 bytes at a time.  Your file has lines that are 9 or 10 bytes long, including the line endings (newline or CR LF).

Comment: Why not make the sample a bit more differentiated, like `12345678 abcdefgh ijklmnop`.  I think that would shed more light during debuging than repeating same digits..

Comment: You should really try debugging it.  Look at your data buffer before & after all syscalls.  Note that your input is using a fixed-count read syscall, so always reading 8, but your output is using a print string syscall that depends on null termination, so if less than 8 is read, well, look at the buffer....